# Stream Iterate hashMap and process the data

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to Iterate the hashmap using java Stream and would like to execute an inline function for each key
and then sum the value

```
Map<Integer, Integer>  myMap= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{ 
                put(5000, 0);
                put(1000, 10);
            }};

myMap.entrySet().stream().map(e-> {/* want to fetch the corresponding value and increment by X  and find the sum*/ });
```

Comment: What is `X`? By value, do you mean `Map.Entry#getValue()`? Can you specify the expected output in the example you posted?

Comment: yes, I want to get value for each key and then increment the value by 10 and want to find the sum. Expecting to get output of 30. Actually I have custom logic to update value before geeting sum. To make it simple I mentioned increment by 10 here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. This should work.

```
final Integer sum = myMap.values()
                         .stream()
                         .map(value-> value + X)
                         .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

iIf you wish to get access to key, try this

```
myMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue() + X) // you can use entry.getKey() to get access to key
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: @upog this will do it.

Comment: If you have some custom logic for calculating the increase you can create a method for it, some like `int getNewValue(int value) { /* ... */ }` and you can provide it to the map function.... `.map(this::getNewValue)`

Comment: Thanks Kiran, Is there any way I can also get access to key inside map function. Like Instead of adding X , to add Key. Sorry For changing the question

Comment: @upog... yes, indeed that changes the logic, that's why I asked in the first place if what you needed (only) the `Map.Entry#getValue()`... to access the key just do `myMap.entrySet()` instead of `myMap.values()` and update the logic inside `map`

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapToInt` to generate an `IntStream` and `sum` to sum the mapped elements.

```
myMap.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .mapToInt(entry -> entry.getValue() + X)
   .sum();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,.when i try , i'm getting below error `Multiple markers at this line
 - Type safety: The method mapToInt(ToIntFunction) belongs to the raw type Stream. References to generic type Stream<T> should be 
  parameterized
 - The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: @upog then the problem is at the declaration of your `myMap` variable. It’s hard to believe that you get these errors with this answer but not with the accepted answer. `mapToInt(…).sum()` does not differ from `map(…).reduce(0, Integer::sum)`, except that it is more more efficient. Even better would be not to add a constant `X` to every element, as basic algebra tells you that this is not different to `.mapToInt(entry -> entry.getValue()).sum() + X * myMap.size()`.

Comment: yes,later I found it was declaration error in my code. I have already accepted other answer. @user7 Thanks for your answer.